# Sending Sqlite database as email attachment in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, email-attachments

I have a simple app which I am using to spike sending attachments.

I have managed to send a text file from the SD card (although I couldn't get this to work with a file created in the apps private area using `openFileOutput(fileName, 0)`) but I now want to send a database.

By debugging I can verify the database exists and has an entry in its only table. My code to send looks like this:

```
gmailButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
gmailButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject line"); 
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"Body of email"); 
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(getDatabasePath("TEST_DB"));
        //uri = file:///data/data/com.gmailspike/databases/TEST_DB
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri); 
        sendIntent.setType("application/octet-stream");

        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent,"Email:"));
    }
})
```

;

However, when the email client opens the attachment has a size of 0 bytes and if I touch to open the attachment the client says the file cannot be found.

Any ideas? I'm not sure the mime type is correct, or even if it is important!

Comment: Have a look at the following SO Answer for a really great example on copying the DB file, sending the email and deleting the copied DB file: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18548255/android-send-xml-file-doesnt-send-attachment/18548685#18548685

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I remember having had an issue like this too, when trying to send an email with an image attachment, linking to a file stored in the apps private data folder. The attachment is just missing.

Using the mail intent opens a **new application** to handle the mail-creation. Therefore you either need to write a [Content Provider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html) to allow other applications access to your private data.

Or copy the content to public area first and add it to the mail intent from there (this only works when a SD-Card is present with most phones). The [External Storage.getExternalStorageDirectory()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29) could maybe used in that case.

Hope this helps to find a solution.

Comment: Ahhh...  I haven't delved into content providers yet so will copy to external storage for starters.

Answer (score 1):

As for the MIME type, it is surely important, since an application has to support it (explicitly or through wildcard) to respond to the intent and to be found via `createChooser`.

I think Gmail for instance accepts `*/*` as MIME type with `ACTION_SEND` but I don't know about other mail clients.

**Edit :** And as for the permission, have a look at the `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` flag from the Intent class : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION

Comment: Thanks for the interesting info re mime types.  I tried the permission flag but it didn't work. I think I'll copy the file to external storage first.